# Bigquery `approx_top_count` on ARRAYS after GROUPBY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
-- Incorrect Query
with base as(
  select 'row1' as row_, [1,2,2,3,3,3] as arr, 1 as val
  union all
  select 'row1', [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5], 1
  union all
  select 'row2', [6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7], 1
)


select row_, sum(val) as val, approx_top_count( (select * from unnest(arr)), 2)
from base
group by row_
```

I'm trying to do two things:
(1) calculate the sum for `val` column.
(2) get the top 2 frequent values for each group.

My query is attached above.

I tried to put the `unnest` statement inside `select` statement, syntax check passed, but it gives a runtime error: **"Scalar subquery produced more than one element"**

I expect to see this result --

```
row_ | val |       f0_      |
-----------------------------
row1 |  2  | [{4,4}, {5,5}] |
row2 |  1  | [{6,6}, {7,7}] |
```

What's the correct way to write it?

Note: The reason I can't do `unnest` inside `from` statement is that `sum(val)` for `row1` would be 15 in that case. That's because there will be 15 rows corresponding to `row1`, each row's `val` is 1 and so the sum would be 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select row_, val, 
  format('%t', (select approx_top_count(x,2) from unnest(arr) x)) top_two
from (
  select row_, sum(val) as val, array_concat_agg(arr) arr
  from base
  group by row_
)
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Any idea about why my query won't work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to unnest those arrays so that you can do the frequency of use calculations, then bring that together as the final step:

```
WITH base AS (
    SELECT 'row1' AS row_, [1,2,2,3,3,3] AS arr, 1 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'row1', [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5], 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'row2', [6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7], 1
    )
, unnested AS (
    SELECT row_, val, arr_item
    FROM base, UNNEST(arr) AS arr_item
    )
, counts AS (
    SELECT row_, val, arr_item, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM unnested
    GROUP BY row_, val, arr_item
    )
, aggregated AS (
    SELECT row_, SUM(val) AS sum_val, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(arr_item, cnt) ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS arr_cnt
    FROM counts
    GROUP BY row_, val
    )
SELECT
      row_
    , sum_val
    , ARRAY<STRUCT<arr_item INT64, cnt INT64>>[(SELECT AS STRUCT arr_cnt[OFFSET(0)]), (SELECT AS STRUCT arr_cnt[OFFSET(1)])] AS f0_
FROM aggregated
```

nb: the above is untested